# Restify Server Content Length Mismatch

Tags: node.js, restify

I setup my own restify server in node to serve HTML:

```
const ServeHTML = (folder: string, page: string, res: Restify.Response, data: Object) => {
    let path:string = __dirname+"/../../"+folder+page;
    let MimeType: string | null = Mime.getType(path);
    if(!MimeType) MimeType = "";
    let body:string = fs.readFileSync(path, "utf8");
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(body, "utf8"),
        'Content-Type': MimeType
    });

    Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key,index) {
        let regex = new RegExp("{{"+key+"}}", 'gi');
        body = body.replace(regex, (<any>data)[key]);
    });
    res.write(body);
    res.end();
}
```

As you can see I am already calculating the Content-Length.  However, I still get the error:

```
GET http://localhost:4000/WebChat net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 200 (OK)
```

What am I doing wrong?